# Spring Security OAuth2: how to add multiple Security Filter Chain of type ResourceServerConfigurer?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I set up a Spring Boot multi modules (5 modules) app with Spring Security OAuth2. Everything works well but as the application is growing I want to separate the security part in each module. The main module enables everything:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class Application {  
  ...
}
```

Now in each module I defined a bean of type `ResourceServerConfigurer`

```
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class Module1SecurityFilterChain extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
      http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy( STATELESS );
      http.antMatcher( "/module1/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( "/module1/resource").authenticated()
            .antMatchers( "/module1/test" ).authenticated()
            .anyRequest().access( "#oauth2.hasScope('webclient')" );
   }
}
```

Same thing with module2:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class Module2SecurityFilterChain extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
      http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy( STATELESS );
      http.antMatcher( "/module2/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( "/module2/resource").authenticated()
            .antMatchers( "/module2/test" ).authenticated()
            .anyRequest().access( "#oauth2.hasScope('webclient')" );
   }
}
```

And so on...

The problem is that only one FilterChain is registered, the one whith `@Order(2)`. I took a look at the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/ResourceServerConfigurer.html) of `ResourceServerConfigurer` and it states this:

> ... if more than one configures the same preoperty, then the last one wins. The configurers are sorted by Order before being applied

How can I proceed to bypass this limitation?
Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**

Doing this (extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` instead of `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`):

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class Module2SecurityFilterChain extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {...}
```

seems to register the filter chain but there is another problem, when I authenticate a user (getting token on `/oauth/token`) I can't acces a resource protected by this chain, I got a `403 Forbidden`. How does this black box work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure multiple matchers using across multiple beans by using `requestMatchers().antMatchers(String...)` like so:

```
@Configuration
public class Module2SecurityFilterChain extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
           .requestMatchers()
               .antMatchers("/module2/**")
           .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/module2/resource").authenticated()
               .antMatchers("/module2/test").authenticated()
               .anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('webclient')");
   }
}
```

It's a little confusing, but when you call `http.antMatcher(String)`, this is stating that you want to match only against that one endpoint. So, calling it twice (once in `Module1SecurityFilterChain` and then again in `Module2SecurityFilterChain`), the second call overrides the first.

However, using `http.requestMatchers().antMatchers(String)` indicates that the given `String` should be added to the existing list of endpoints being already matched. You can think of `antMatcher` as a bit like "`setMatcher`" and `antMatchers` like "`appendMatcher`".

Comment: Thanks for replying, I want to try your suggestion but there isn't the method `authorizeRequests()` after `http.requestMatchers().antMatchers(String)`

Comment: I accept the response (after editing it to add  the `and()` method ^^) even if it's not exactly what I wanted but the goal seems to be the same. In fact I wanted to define multiple FilterChain but with you answer, there is only one mapped to all module's request. Like each module's security configuration is separated it's also a good option. Spring Security isn't easy to undestand at all, a real black box. Thanks again for your answer

Comment: Another question, why with `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` we do not have this behavior? I mean, why its `http.antMatcher(String)` creates another FilterChain and doesn't override the others?

Comment: I have another issue related to this solution, please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54030887/6643803